# Thunderbird not prompting for SMTP password, and password does not already exist

Tags: email, passwords, thunderbird, smtp

I'm using Thunderbird for work mail on Linux Mint 21.2. We have an IMAP server for incoming mail and SMTP for outgoing. Logging in to IMAP works fine, I receive and can read all my emails. However, when I try to send email, I get `Login to server name.domain with username myusername failed`, with the options to Enter New Password, Cancel, or Retry. However, when I click Enter New Password, the dialog box quickly closes and pops up again, I'm not able to enter a new password at all. It's the same when I click Retry of course.

When I hit cancel, I get a new dialog `Send Message Error: Sending of the message failed. Unable to authenticate to Outgoing server (SMTP) name.domain. Please check the password and verify the 'Authentication method' in 'Account Settings | Outgoing server (SMTP)'`.

So, I checked Authentication method, which is Kerberos/GSSAPI, which aligns with my organization's instructions for setting up Thunderbird (Connection Security is STARTTLS if that matters, which also aligns with instructions).

When I go to my saved passwords, I have a password for my imap provider and for TbSync - there is no saved SMTP password. I tried removing both the existing ones, and had to enter them again when logging in/syncing TbSync. However, the same error persists when trying to send email. I have never been prompted for an SMTP password.

Is there any way for me to fix this on my side or does it sound like server-side issues?

Comment: At the very bottom of your account settings, there is the SMTP accounts settings. Although you cannot enter a password there, it is that location where you need to remove and add them again. After that, going to your account settings at the bottom, you have SMTP server, ensure that it is correct. Normally that should work.

Comment: I only have the default server on this list, and there is no option to remove it. If I add a new server with the same information, I still have the same problem. EDIT: I tried adding a new server with the correct information, setting that as default, and deleting the old one. Still the same problem.

Comment: Does your service provide webmail? If so try to login there and send an email. This will tell you if the service is still working or not (aka server-side issue)

Comment: Yes, the webmail is working fine so I guess that's ruled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not able to enter a new password at all.
> [...]
> So, I checked Authentication method, which is Kerberos/GSSAPI,

That's normal – Thunderbird isn't supposed to save or prompt for Kerberos passwords at all. It expects the OS to already have Kerberos credentials available.

- Make sure you have the correct hostname for the SMTP server. Kerberos relies on the app knowing what server name it's connecting to (even more than TLS does), otherwise the app may be obtaining the wrong ticket or not able to obtain one at all.

  (Check `klist` to see what tickets have been acquired so far.)
- Make sure you're connecting to the appropriate port (usually 465 or 587, *not* 25).
- Try **clearing** the "username" setting, to have the server guess it from the Kerberos ticket instead.
- Run Thunderbird from within a terminal, after setting `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr`. See what it outputs when trying to send a message.
- Test other software; for example, install the GSASL tools and try using it to connect to the SMTP server with Kerberos authentication:

  ```
  gsasl --smtp mail.example.com 587
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!

I have the correct hostname I believe, as gsasl receives a "service ready" message and a "hello" from ESMTP MAIL Service, and then "SMTP server ready". But after AUTH GSSAPI and 332 GSSAPI supported, I get `gsasl: mechanism error: Base 64 coding error in SASL library`.

As for running thunderbird in terminal, I get the following whenever I try to send an email:
`console.error: mailnews.smtp: ({})`
`console.error: mailnews.smtp: "Authentication failed: AUTH GSSAPI"`

Comment: After closing the error dialog in Thunderbird I actually got another line of info in the kernel with `exitCode=2153066805`. Googling that led me to [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1361501), and I tried the suggested answer (using `Normal Password` instead of Kerberos, then restarting). I swear I'd tried `Normal Password` earlier and it didn't work, but it did this time! Possibly had to do with the restart, or maybe came from my earlier attempt to delete the original SMTP setting. Thanks for sending me down the right path.

Comment: Well, none of that really indicates "correct hostname", as a server could have many hostnames but only one (or some) of them are known to the Kerberos KDC. (As for the base64 error... for 334 that would indicate a server issue – it's not supposed to send arbitrary text in 334 – but for 332 I'm not sure.) Do you get a success result from `kvno smtp/YOUR.SERVER.NAME`, then?